# get details of source repository from Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

A Jenkinsfile uses a `checkout scm` command to retrieve the most recent commit from a linked Bitbucket respository.

> What specific syntax needs to be added to the Jenkinsfile in order for the Jenkinsfile to be able to extract the `repositorySlug`, and `projectKey` from the source repository as variables, and then print out those variables as console output?**

---

**Sample Jenkinsfile:**

---

I tried to incorporate ideas from the [Jenkins Pipeline SCM Step Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) in the following example Jenkinsfile whose resulting logs will be shown further below:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            def commitHash = checkout(scm).GIT_COMMIT
            sh "echo 'Commit hash is: ${commitHash}'"
            println commitHash

            def repName = checkout(scm).repoName
            sh "echo 'Repository Name is: ${repName}'"
            println repName

            def rep = checkout(scm).repo
            sh "echo 'Repository is: ${rep}'"
            println rep

            def nm = checkout(scm).name
            sh "echo 'Name is: ${nm}'"
            println nm
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

---

**Current Output:**

---

Here is the console output that Jenkins generates when running the preceding Jenkinsfile:

```
General SCM<1s
echo 'Commit hash is: bd279b90ad9f78ee8abb4d4fbf2a621d42150dd3'— Shell Script<1s
bd279b90ad9f78ee8abb4d4fbf2a621d42150dd3— Print Message<1s
General SCM<1s
    > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
    Fetching without tags
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/sample-issue-branch:refs/remotes/origin/sample-issue-branch
    Checking out Revision bd279b90ad9f78ee8abb4d4fbf2a621d42150dd3 (sample-issue-branch)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f bd279b90ad9f78ee8abb4d4fbf2a621d42150dd3
    Commit message: "name"
    [Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
echo 'Repository Name is: null'— Shell Script<1s
null— Print Message<1s
General SCM<1s
echo 'Repository is: null'— Shell Script<1s
null— Print Message<1s
General SCM<1s
echo 'Name is: null'— Shell Script<1s
null— Print Message<1s
```

Note that the `projectKey` and the `repositorySlug` are available in the logs above in the form of:

```
http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
```

---

**Restated Question:**

---

> **For the data above, what specific syntax would need to be added to the Jenkinsfile in order for the resulting Jenkins logs to print out the following:**

```
The projectKey is: JSP
The repositorySlug is: jenkinsfile-simple-repo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but there might be a simpler way I'm presently not aware of.

Basically, it retrieves the full URL returned by the SCM plugin, splits it by `/` and extracts the parts you need.

```
def repoUrl = checkout(scm).GIT_URL
def key = repoUrl.tokenize('/')[3]
def slug = repoUrl.tokenize('/')[4]
slug = slug.substring(0, slug.lastIndexOf('.')) //Remove .git
echo "The projectKey is: ${key}"
echo "The repositorySlug is: ${slug}"
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to throw light on this area.  My delay in reply is due to significant difference in our time zones.